# why $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', '0') is not working in codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, remember-me

`Why $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', '0');` is not overriding $config['sess_expire_on_close']   = TRUE; which is my default config setting.

Bassically i want if a user click a remember me check box 
`$this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', '0')` in the controller works and not the   default `$config['sess_expire_on_close']   = TRUE;`